Facebook Open Graph Debugger not picking new og:url with trailing slash and complaining about circular redirect
I have been improving my SEO and fixing canonical urls and realized that there was a trailing slach problem on one of my URLs.
I have fixed this on my webpage (thanks to this SO), and now my og:url metas seem to be generated appropriately, but despite clearing facebook cache, it seems like facebook still complains about a bad config.
See this URL on the FB Crawler
And the screenshot at the time of writing this post

Any idea what might be wrong ? Url is https://rockit.dance/events/
